# For ARCore TramsformableNode, Pinch getsture doesn't work at the first time

Tags: arcore, sceneform

Pinch gesture only works after the first touch events, either users touch the 3d object first or drag the 3d object first.

Comment: In order to pinch, scale, rotate a `TransformableNode` in SceneForm, you need to first select it. Notice a ring forms around the object. You may carry out your gesture events then.

Comment: Thanks! btw, how do u know this? I didn't get any hits from ARCore tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

To scale a TransformableNode, it must be selected. You can ensure that the TransformableNode is selected when it is first created by calling TransformableNode.select().

Comment: Please share the code of PinchGesture after TransformableNode.select(). I want to scale the object and want to get its size. How to do this?

Comment: TransformableNode has the pinch, drag and scale gestures by defualt.

Comment: After scaling the node, and getting its Locale in vector, the vector comes as x = 8.5, y=8.5, z=8.5. How to convert it into normal unit meters?